# How can I find out the name of the user when in a ASP.Net Web API Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is some sample code from my controller:

```
public class ContentController : ApiController
{
    private IContentService _contentService;

    public ContentController(
        IContentService contentService)
    {
        _contentService = contentService;
    }

    // GET api/Content/5
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("GetContent")]
    public Content GetContent(int Id)
    {
        Content content = _uow.Contents.GetById(Id);
        if (content == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }
        return content;
    }
```

I would like to find the Id of the user. Can someone tell me how I can do this? I'm using the standard ASP.NET Simple Authentication and I have used an ASP.NET MVC account controller to login my user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the api controller you can simply use:

```
User.Identity.Name
```

Check that

```
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

first.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Forms Authentication you can try use the `HttpContext` class and the `Identity` property:

```
var currentUser = HttpContext.User.Identity;
```